# Django parsing arguments

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm using an AJAX call to get data from the server:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/simple/gd/',
 dataType: 'json',
 data: {t : "PL"},
 success: function(data) {
 var newd = data['t'];
  alert('Load was performed: ' + newd);
 }
});
```

On the server, urls.py is:

```
(r'^simple/gd/(?P<data>.*)$', 'simple.views.getData'),
```

The url that's getting to the server is http:/localhost/simple/gd/?t=PL

But for some reason, I can't make getData(request, data) to be called with "?t=PL" or with "t=PL" as 'data' parameter. 'data' is always empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use type: 'POST' then the data doesn't get appended to the URL as a query string.

Instead, it is included in the request object's POST dictionary.

So in order to pass something back that fires your alert you need to render a string that can be interpreted as json data something along the lines of:

```
(r'^simple/gd/$', 'simple.views.getData'),

def getData(request):
    posted_t = request.POST['t']
    # Do some stuff with posted_t
    server_side_var = "Yay"
    return HttpResponse(u"{t:%s}" % server_side_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `t=PL` is not part of the path, it's the query string (the path, roughly speaking, is the bit before the `?`, the query string is the bit after the `?`).

Personally, I'd recommend changing your `urls.py` as follows:

```
(r'^simple/gd/$', 'simple.views.getData'),
```

Then, adjust your view function from something like:

```
def getData(request, data):
    print data
```

to something like:

```
def getData(request):
    print request.GET.get('t', None)
```

Comment: What if my 'data' is more complex? For example, 
    data = { t: "me", m : { a : "you", b : "we"}}

I would like to get the whole "data" as is, and parse it with python

Comment: If you want data in the path then it can only be flat data (unless you are going to get very clever!) /me/you/we/ - what is the problem with reading a POST variable?